# use of hibernate envers with inheritance

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-envers

Kindly suggest me how to do auditing with inheritance type table per subclass because I am not able to find any documentation for this. I have tried it on my code but it is not working properly. If I make parent table "@Audited" then my derived class must be audited automatically because they should inherit the behavior from parent class. My code is as follows

```
@Entity  
@Table(name = "employee105")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)   
@Audited
public class Employee {   
@Id  
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)         
@Column(name = "id")
private int id;   

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;
// getter setter
```

}

```
@Entity  
@Table(name="contractemployee105")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="ID") 
@Audited
public class OldEmployee extends Employee{   

    @Column(name="pay_per_hour")
    private Long pay_per_hour;          

    @Column(name="contract_duration")
    private String contract_duration;
  // getter and setter
 }

@Entity  
@Table(name="regularemployee105")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="ID")
@Audited
public class NewEmployee extends Employee{   

@Column(name="salary")
private Long salary;   

@Column(name="bonus")
private Integer bonus;
// getter and setter
}
```

In the above code all the tables are being generated i.e. all 3 entity table , 3 audit table and one REVINFO table but no data is being inserted in them. Kindly tell me if I am missing anything. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just got the workaround thus upgraded my hibernate from 3.5 to 4.2 and everything is working  fine now. I think there is some bug in hibernate envers 3.5 and it is resolved in later versions.